# How to initialize a static object using spring(@autowired)

Tags: spring, performance, autowired

I am very new with spring framework and I wanted to initialize a object at compile time like this...

```
@Autowired
private static Configuration config;

private static String key = config.getXXX();
private static String path = config.getYYY();
```

But I will get null pointer since **config** is not **initialized**.

So, how to do the same with autowire? and is it a good practice to code like this?

Answer (score 0):

The Configuration bean should have singleton as scope, singleton has somehow the same meaning as Java singleton but only for the current Spring application context.
Then you can call the getXXX() and getYYY() methods from your code, but not in the place your using it now.